# Returning correct value from VBA script to Excel cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a method I wrote in a VBA module

```
Public Function calcAscentTime()

IDepth = CInt(Sheets("Fundies").Range("B47"))
T = 0

T = T + 1   ' Add 1 minute for emergency
D = Math.Round((IDepth / 10) * 10) 'Round to Ceiling of nearest 10

half_depth = Math.Round(((D / 2) / 10) * 10, 0)  'Get where our first stop is
T = T + Math.Round((((D - half_depth) / 30) / 2) * 2) ' Ascend to first stop at 30ft/min

T = T + (half_depth / 10) ' 1 minute for every stop thereafter
```

What this does is take a value from Cell B47 on the "Fundies" worksheet and should return a value based on the calculations.  I enter =calcAscentTime() into cell B48, expecting to get a value of 8(B47's value is 100), but get a return value of 0.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You missed one last line: `calcAscentTime = T`

Answer (score 0):

ou're function isn't returning anything.  Assigning the function name to the calculated variable should return the expected result (assuming you have everything else right).  Something like:

```
Public Function calcAscentTime()

IDepth = CInt(Sheets("Fundies").Range("B47"))
T = 0

T = T + 1   ' Add 1 minute for emergency
D = Math.Round((IDepth / 10) * 10) 'Round to Ceiling of nearest 10

half_depth = Math.Round(((D / 2) / 10) * 10, 0)  'Get where our first stop is
T = T + Math.Round((((D - half_depth) / 30) / 2) * 2) ' Ascend to first stop at 30ft/min

T = T + (half_depth / 10) ' 1 minute for every stop thereafter
calcAscentTime = T
End Function
```

Keep in mind, you should probably Dim your variables to the proper type to avoid any kind of confusion / miss-casting by the compiler.